# SQL Anywhere - SELECT COUNT(PK) WHERE [Conditions] performance

Tags: sql, performance, query-performance, sqlanywhere

I have a query similar to the one below and am trying to find ways of decreasing execution time. I've tried adding normal indexes, but from what I've read using LIKE % string % means the database can't use them. I've also tried adding text indexes and using CONTAINS(AColumn, String) but that also didn't seem to speed things up (I also couldn't find a way to completely mimic the match anywhere behavior with contains). Is there a better way to find a count of rows based on string matching for this scenario? Being able to search AColumn from TableA and BColumn from TableB is a must.

```
SELECT COUNT(TableA.PK) 
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN 
     TableB 
WHERE (AColumn LIKE '%String%' OR BColumn LIKE '%STRING%')
```

Comment: Thats a good start ! did you looked at execution plan, and it does suggest something. I would isolate queries with 2 like operators and do a union all for effective output

Comment: @Ande . . . The use of `LIKE` with wildcards at the beginning and end -- and on columns in both tables -- is going to preclude most optimizations.  Can you switch to a full-text search instead?

Comment: @Ven I pulled up the execution plan, but I don't think I'm knowledgeable enough to get anything from it. I did try a union, doing something like I've added below, and while it was around 20% faster on my test database, it was actually slower on the production database. The production database has 8 threads available to it while the test one only has 2, not sure if that matters.

Comment: @Ven  
     SELECT COUNT(*)  
     FROM  
     (  
          SELECT(TableA.PK)  
          FROM TableA  
          LEFT JOIN TableB  
          WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%String%'  
     UNION  
          SELECT(TableA.PK)  
          FROM TableA  
          LEFT JOIN TableB  
          WHERE ColumnB LIKE '%String%'  
     ) t

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried adding a text index to the columns and doing a full-text search using the SQL Anywhere CONTAINS() function, but it ended up being slower than using LIKE.

Comment: @Ande i guess its your  `left join` is issue rather `like operator `, why cant you do inner join ?

Comment: @Ven Sorry, this wasn't made clear by my original post. Table A has a foreign key refence to TableB, but it is only populated around 10% of the time. In the actual case I have, there are four columns from table A being compared to the string and one column from table B. Even limiting the query to the columns from table A and removing the join takes longer than desired. A lot of these search strings will be repeats, so I'm thinking I might have to just accept the long execution time of the first query, and implement a caching system to speed up subsequent ones.